# Mysql: one big query vs several individual queries

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a Yii2 project and I'm using a form with [autocomplete](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-autocomplete.html) feature. Something like the example in the documentation:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'attibute')->widget(AutoComplete::classname(), [
    'clientOptions' => [
        'source' => ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
    ],
]) ?>
```

This widget needs that we populate the `source` with all autocomplete values and, in my scenario, the values are coming from another model.

I'm wondering if I should make a `select` to get all distinct values of this model in my db when the page loads or is better implement a way of, only while the user is typing, make a search of 10-20 values that match so far and update the result.

I'm not really concerned about the code, I'm sure I can find a lot of examples on the internet if I face any trouble. My problem is knowing what is best for this scenario. One big query with all values or individual ones each time the user type a new digit? I would like to undertand wich one suits better here (or another way) and why.

At the moment I have around 3k values stored in my db.

Comment: I would say, it depends on how many values we're talking about. If there aren't that many, getting them all in one go and implement the autocomplete feature in pure JS will probably be a lot faster (no extra requests to the web server or queries against the DB).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson And that is my dilemma. As i said, at the moment I have around 3k values stored in my db. This number will increase over time. Both methods work great with 3k. But what about when i have like 6k or 10k? Loading all at once will slow down the page every time the page loads, but, in another hand, loading only when the user is typing makes the system do almost 4-7 small searchs (i'm guessing with 7 letters, they probably found what they are trying to type) for each time this field is used.

Comment: Now, I'm wondering why people voted to close this question. This is not a primarily opinion-based question, since or I'm not asking what is cool to do here, but what will have the best performance over time (maybe is obvious for some people, but, when it comes to database, I don't have much knowledge). If I didn't make myself clear at some point, let me know. I will update the question.

Comment: I just stumbled in here. I could see this closing as Too Broad, Unclear, or POB. But fear not, it won't close. It will just get ignored probably unless someone has such time to write up thoughts like on quora dot com

Comment: I will suggest you load data once and display in dropdown.